# How to code my HTTP response header for 8 hours in the future in php/

Tags: php, http-headers

I know how to set a basic expires HTTP response header in PHP as follows...

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

However, I want to make it a little more dynamic in that I want to, using PHP, specify an expiration time eight hours ahead of when the user accesses the content.  Could someone help me achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*Cache-Control*’s *max-age*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) instead that indicated the number of second relative to the response time:

> The expiration time of an entity MAY be specified by the origin server using the Expires header (see section 14.21). Alternatively, it MAY be specified using the max-age directive in a response. When the max-age cache-control directive is present in a cached response, the response is stale if its current age is greater than the age value given (in seconds) at the time of a new request for that resource.

An example:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');
```

Note that if both *Expires* and *Cache-Control*’s *max-age* are present, *max-age* is preferred over *Expires*:

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive.

Comment: @Drew2345: *Pragma* with what value?

Comment: I am not sure, that's why I am asking ;)  I read http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#PRAGMA but am uncertain, given my above situation, what I should set this value to.

Comment: @Drew2345: Well, the [behavior for `Pragma: no-cache` in a response is not specified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32): “Note: because the meaning of "Pragma: no-cache as a response header field is not actually specified, it does not provide a reliable replacement for "Cache-Control: no-cache" in a response.” So it’s quite useless. Use [`Cache-Control: no-cache`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) instead if you want a cached response not to be used by a cache without revalidation.

Comment: What about this: header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=28800, must-revalidate'); header('Expires:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+8 hours'))); header('Pragma: private');

Comment: @Drew2345: Well, *private* means the response is only cacheable by local caches and not by shared caches; *max-age* specifies the freshness lifetime; and *must-revalidate* requires the client to revalidate the cached entry. So a response may be cached by private caches only and must revalidate the cached response after it became stale (i.e. after the 28800 seconds). But the behavior of `Pragma: private` is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to make a timestamp in the future, and [gmdate](http://php.net/gmdate) to format it as a string in the GMT timezone.

```
define('EXPIRE_FORMAT', 'D, d M Y H:i:s T');
$expires = gmdate(EXPIRE_FORMAT, strtotime('+8 hours'));
header("Expires: $expires");
```

Comment: `strtotime()` is hideously slow compared to `$expires = gmdate(time() + 8*86400);` by a factor of ~7

Comment: If the server is automatically sending an Expires response by default, can I override/null that out with a php script so that the expires header field is not set?

Comment: Marc B, you are of course correct. The call to strtotime can be exchanged for `time() + 8*86400` for those who like micro-optimization. time() is also "hideously slow" compared to $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ;-)

Comment: Drew2345, that probably depends on the server. Try!